# How to physically secure my laptop in my office desk?

Tags: security

I work in an open plan area. We have "hot desks" (first come first serve). I use a laptop and don't want to carry it with me all the time. How can I leave it in the desk, making sure it is not possible (under reasonable circumstances) to steal it?

One option is to get a drawer with a lock. That's what I am currently asking for. Yet, I am curious of other ways. Any experience about this?

UPDATE on company.

We are a small and fairly new company, nothing like a big firm with strict and clear IT procedures and practices. No rules on locking or so. My employer own the PC since it paid for it, but we can also use it for our private purposes at home. In the end, it is understood that if users leave the company, they will pay off the laptop (if still fine) for a few hundred dollars, which is in any way much cheaper, given that the laptops are quite nice. So it's kind of "its a company laptop but well, kind of mine in the end". Don't expect too much in terms of rules or enforcement.

Comment: The standard (non-hack) solution is a [Kensington lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot). My company insists that all laptops are secured when left unattended, especially at night.

Comment: Do you own the laptop or does the company you work for own the laptop?

Comment: As you don't own the machine the suggestion by @Stephie in the comments to use specific device is not going to work for you.  Can you update your question to include that the company owns the machine and what their protection policy is?  Are you obligated to keep it with you at all times (i.e. trip to the bathroom)? Are you working in a secure building? Are you obligated to lock (crtl + alt + L) your laptop and use a strong password when it is unattended? Anything else related?

Comment: @JamesJenkins not sure - my employer *owns* the laptop I work with everyday, but I *use* it and e.g. have a specific software installed. OTOH, some of our facilities don’t assign fixed desks any longer. OP may be in a similar situation?

Comment: @Stephie I assume your employer installed the physical lock. They probably purchased the machine with it installed.  I also assume that the OP is prohibited from physically altering the machine, in my cases (like mine) any software also needs company approval.

Comment: @Stephie given the recent comment by OP you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @JamesJenkins a Kensington lock needs no physical alterations - many laptops simply come with that little “slot” where the end of the cable goes to. And the lock itself is around 30€...

Comment: @JamesJenkins seems so - will do, when I have more time.

Comment: @Stephie Look like a decent security system. Surely trivial to break with decent pliers, but I guess for short term pauses its probably alright.

Comment: @laudate You'd be surprised - a decent quality Kensington Lock will stop most attempts to cut it short of bolt butters. They aren't perfect - but you usually can't get them off with out at least moderately damaging the laptop they are connected to.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Kensington locks don't generally require modifying he hardware anyway as most business-grade laptops already have the appropriate "slot" for them.

Comment: @motosubatsu on closer look my work laptop also has this, and reading in Wikipedia [Several manufacturers offer similar locking mechanisms that do not require a special lock hole. They attach to a popular port, such as the VGA or printer port, and have special screws to secure locks in place.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot#Alternatives)

Comment: @laudate, some manufacturers will add a circuit or something around the Kensington lock hole so if the lock is forcefully removed and it gets damaged, the laptop is useless.

Comment: There are clones of the Kensington locks that are even more inexpensive- one local store has Belkin ones for CAD 9.88 plus tax. Of course it's better in many circumstances to just take the notebook computer with you.

Answer (score 2):

Short of riveting the laptop to the desk top, the only real method is a cable/lock combination designed to prevent theft. Kensington is just one brand.  Most laptop manufacturers (HP, Dell, Lenovo, etc.) market their own house brand and one is as good as another.

An important point might be that the manufacturer's brand might be the best if it was designed for that particular laptop.